Why do I sometimes need extern keyword and sometimes not?
I apologize in advance: this question has surely been asked and replied many times before. But I searched and was not able to find any answer... So:
I write a video-game emulator for an Arduino Nano ESP32 (MCU ESP32-S3), using C++, VS Code with PlatformIO and Arduino Framework. Cross-compiling is done with xtensa-esp32s3-elf-g++ from my Debian PC to the dev board.
I test my program with different ROMs ripped from game cartridges. Those ROMs have been "translated" in .cpp files so I get an array of bytes to be executed by the emulated processor.
Here's how the variables defined in this "ROM .cpp file" are declared in corresponding header (.h) file:
extern uint8_t rom[];

extern const int rom_size;
extern const char bios_name[];
extern const char rom_name[];

This header file is then included in the processor emulator .cpp source code file.
The variables are defined this way in the ROM file:
const int rom_size = ROM_SIZE;
const char bios_name[] = BIOS_NAME;
const char rom_name[] = ROM_NAME;

uint8_t rom[ROM_SIZE] = {

Source code files are compiling and linking OK, no problem until today.
Today I changed from one ROM to another. Then I got this linker error:
/home/gregoire/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32s3/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32s3-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32s3-elf/bin/ld: .pio/build/arduino_nano_esp32/src/travolta.cpp.o:(.literal._Z5setupv+0xc): undefined reference to `bios_name'
/home/gregoire/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32s3/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32s3-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32s3-elf/bin/ld: .pio/build/arduino_nano_esp32/src/travolta.cpp.o:(.literal._Z5setupv+0x14): undefined reference to `rom_name'
/home/gregoire/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32s3/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32s3-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32s3-elf/bin/ld: .pio/build/arduino_nano_esp32/src/travolta.cpp.o:(.literal._Z5setupv+0x1c): undefined reference to `rom_size'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio/build/arduino_nano_esp32/firmware.elf] Error 1

I first suspected the linker was not taking into account my new ROM file. But using a verbose mode I got confirmation that it's included in the linking process:
Building in release mode
xtensa-esp32s3-elf-g++ -o .pio/build/arduino_nano_esp32/firmware.elf -mlongcalls -Wl,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections -fno-rtti -fno-lto -Wl,--wrap=esp_log_write -Wl,--wrap=esp_log_writev -Wl,--wrap=log_printf -Wl,--wrap=longjmp -Wl,--undefined=uxTopUsedPriority -T memory.ld -T sections.ld -T esp32s3.rom.ld -T esp32s3.rom.api.ld -T esp32s3.rom.libgcc.ld -T esp32s3.rom.newlib.ld -T esp32s3.rom.version.ld -T esp32s3.rom.newlib-time.ld -T esp32s3.peripherals.ld -u _Z5setupv -u _Z4loopv -u esp_app_desc -u pthread_include_pthread_impl -u pthread_include_pthread_cond_impl -u pthread_include_pthread_local_storage_impl -u pthread_include_pthread_rwlock_impl -u include_esp_phy_override -u ld_include_highint_hdl -u start_app -u start_app_other_cores -u __ubsan_include -u __assert_func -u vfs_include_syscalls_impl -u app_main -u newlib_include_heap_impl -u newlib_include_syscalls_impl -u newlib_include_pthread_impl -u newlib_include_assert_impl -u __cxa_guard_dummy -Wl,-Map="/home/gregoire/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/Travolta/.pio/build/arduino_nano_esp32/firmware.map" .pio/build/arduino_nano_esp32/FrameworkArduinoVariant/dfu_callbacks.cpp.o .pio/build/arduino_nano_esp32/FrameworkArduinoVariant/double_tap.c.o .pio/build/arduino_nano_esp32/FrameworkArduinoVariant/io_pin_remap.cpp.o .pio/build/arduino_nano_esp32/FrameworkArduinoVariant/variant.cpp.o .pio/build/arduino_nano_esp32/src/cartridge_rip.cpp.o .pio/build/arduino_nano_esp32/src/mnemonics.cpp.o

"cartridge_rip.cpp.o" is the name of the object file resulting from the compilation of my ROM file. So it's included in the linker input files.
To get rid of that error I had to add the extern keyword to the three problematic variables definitions:
extern const int rom_size = ROM_SIZE;
extern const char bios_name[] = BIOS_NAME;
extern const char rom_name[] = ROM_NAME;
uint8_t rom[ROM_SIZE] = {

Now linking is OK and I get my executable firmware:
esptool.py v4.5.1
Creating esp32s3 image...
Merged 2 ELF sections
Successfully created esp32s3 image.

When going back to my first ROM I'm still able to link without those supplementary extern keywords !
What's more, linker doesn't need me to add this keyword to the rom variable....
Probably missing something obvious but what ?

Probably missing something obvious but what?  No, you are not missing something obvious — the rules are complicated.  When extern storage/linkage specifier is omitted, some situations extern is implied, and other situations it is presume to be not-extern (you need to provide extern explicitly, as in the cases you cited).  Those situations depend on declaration versus definition, when other storage/linkage specifiers are provided, and if the thing is a const or non-const.

There are differences you're not showing us. You'd need to post complete
minimal examples exhibiting the difference.

My guess is that your second example failed to include the header file.

@Mike Kinghan comment was right: there's one difference I forgot to mention (because I didn't even see it): one file has a .cpp extension while other one has a .c one... And this was the point: using .cpp extension I need to add extern keyword while using .c it's useless. For both files just changing filename extension gives the same result so this is clearly tied. My code is in fact plain C but due to using Arduino framework which is written in C++ I tend to also use .cpp even for C code. I guess due to mangling or something like this the compiler doesn't treat both files the same way.

@GrégoireTELLIER Nothing to do with mangling. Eugene's answer is correct.

You have encountered a difference between C and C++ language standards. In C, const implies extern. In C++, it implies static. The latter allows putting things like const int size = 10; in a header. In C, that would lead to a duplicate definition.
